# Change View of a page after sending data

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Initially I am rendering `Upload file` text with a button.After clicking this it is calling `_handleSubmit` which sends file to an API.
  After this sending is done I want to change  `Upload file` `to Upload done`.For that I have created a variable `isSend` but not able to use it.

```
 _handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const fl = new FormData();
    fl.append("name", this.state.file);
    const req = request
      .post("/upload")
      .send(fl);
    req.end(function (err, response) {
      if (response=== "OK") {
        this.setState({//not setting showing error
          isSend: true
        });
      }
    });

  }



 render() {
    const isSend = this.state.isSend; //false initially
    return (
      <div>
          <h3>Upload file</h3> //Show done upload after done

            <button 
                    type="submit"
                    onClick={(e) => this._handleSubmit(e)}>Upload File
            </button>
        </div>

    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to `bind` the `context`, Use this:

```
req.end((err, response) => {
     if (response=== "OK") {
        this.setState({  //it will work
            isSend: true
        });
     }
 });
```

or use `.bind(this)` with callback method, like this:

```
req.end( function(err, response) {
    if (response=== "OK") {
      this.setState({  //it will work
          isSend: true
      });
    }
}.bind(this));
```

And check the value of `isSend` inside render method to change the text, like this:

```
render() {
    const isSend = this.state.isSend; //false initially
    return (
        <div>
            <h3> {isSend ? 'Upload Done' : 'Upload file' } </h3> 
            <button 
                type="submit"
                onClick={(e) => this._handleSubmit(e)}>Upload File
            </button>
        </div>

    )
}
```